# Live USB "Check disk for defects” finds defects but doesn't list them

Tags: system-installation, xubuntu, live-usb, disk-check

I downloaded the iso file for XUbuntu. I created a live usb using Pen Drive Linux. I turned on my computer, booted to the XUbuntu installation screen, and selected "check disk for defects".

A minute later, it says that it found one defect. How do I figure out what this defect is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“Check disk for defects” will compare the checksums of the files on the USB drive against a known good list. The result means there was an error transferring the Xubuntu live system to the USB drive.

- Did you follow the [official instructions to create a bootable USB drive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)?
- Did you [check the integrity](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM) of the downloaded ISO image? In case of an error here, re-download the image.

Comment: I already checked the integrity of the ISO image. I also followed the directions on how to create a bootable USB drive.

Comment: Mh… try to re-format the USB drive and make it bootable again. If that doesn't work, either the USB drive or the image itself is broken (which is hard to imagine since it's so likely to be discovered by the developers).

Comment: Is it safe to install XUbuntu?

Comment: It's extremely unlikely to damage your computer, but it may result in “random” behaviour if an important file is damaged. The most likely being an error, crash, or freeze.

Comment: You also need to verify the integrity of the USB.

Comment: Hard to believe this answer is considered a predecessor of me asking how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the integrity of the image written to the USB drive by checking it's MD5 sum against the original ISO's checksum:

## Check the original ISO's size:

```
% ls -l archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso 

-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 689963008 nov 22 21:35 archlinux-2015.10.01-dual.iso
```

### $SIZE = 689963008

## Run this command, changing $SIZE according to the original ISO's size and replacing /dev/sdc with the actual device path:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdc iflag=fullblock count=$(($SIZE/512)) 2>/dev/null | md5sum -
```

## Check the output against the original ISO's MD5 sum.