# Ubuntu Gnome 16.10 Failed Boot in VM

Tags: system-installation, kernel, 16.10

I am new to the Linux OS.

I am trying to run a VM with Ubuntu Gnome 16.10. I am installing with an .iso file and once it installs completely I am prompted to restart the machine. After I do this I receive a kernel panic:

[image]

Comment: Check for your BIOS configuration in my computer it is F2 but it could be different in your

Comment: Try making a Live USB and try it in a live session. This doesn't do anything to the Hard Drive

Comment: @userDepth This is a virtual machine.

Comment: @KazWolfe So let's take that out but he also needs to know his BIOS setup tool. Or check the ISO integrity  first ?

Comment: @userDepth It's always a good idea to check integrity before install, but BIOS in this case really doesn't exist outside of the VM config menus. And, for the most part, Ubuntu should work with whatever we throw at it.

Comment: @KazWolfe got ya

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://askubuntu.com/questions/532218/live-usb-check-disk-for-defects-finds-defects-but-doesnt-list-them